# ubuntu freeze when I plugged the power cable

Tags: 12.10, freeze, ubuntu-bug

I recently update the system(12.10) on my laptop and after that whenever I plug the power cable in to my laptop it freezes and has no function of the mouse or the keyboard. I have to reboot the laptop and after that it's fully functional.(with the power cable plugged in.)

I need help to troubleshoot this problem or to report it as a bug if that is required.

Comment: It seems to me a bug related to kernel and acpi. I would try booting an older kernel first and see if the problem is related to a kernel update.

Comment: I did boot to another kernel but when booted up there is no unity(dash). :(

Comment: Try booting with the `acpi=off` option. In Grub press e and add it to the line containing `quiet splash` and report back.

Comment: I've got the same issue and it only started appearing recently. I'd love to hear a fix for this, because all I found online didn't help.

Comment: Do you have Jupiter installed in your system?

Comment: if you have it installed in your system i advise you to uninstall it. because even i had faced the same problem in 12.10..once i removed jupiter the problem was resolved

Comment: What *exact* laptop do you have? Did you consider using another kernel version? (e.g. from [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)) To what extent is the computer frozen? Can you still access a VT? (Ctrl+Alt+F1) Can you reboot it using the [magic SysRq REISUB](http://injustfiveminutes.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/how-to-reboot-a-frozen-linux-box-with-reisub/) method?

Comment: Same here, Kernel Panic if I generate the issue from tty1

Comment: Are you using the xorg edgers ppa?

Comment: @Mukund : Yeah I had Jupiter installed in my system and now I had removed it and my system works perfectly. No more freezing, So thanks a lot. Is this means I can't use Jupiter anymore? Is there any bug-fixed version of Jupiter.? Thanks again..!

Comment: @DoGoDo , jasmines : Try removing Jupiter.

Comment: @gertvdijk : I have Dell N5010 now I guess it doesn't matter, thanks anyway..!

Comment: @jasmines : " xorg edgers ppa", I don't know what that means, sorry.! try removing Jupiter for your system.

Comment: @Sudheera Im glad that it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Do you have Jupiter installed on your system?

If you do, I advise you to uninstall it. I faced the same problem in 12.10 but removing Jupiter fixed it.

Additionally, according to [their official website](http://jupiter.sourceforge.net/downloads.html), "Jupiter Applet has been retired and is no longer supported software." This might go some way to explain why it's now causing problems.

---

***Note from a moderator:** This answer was shown to fix things in the comments.:*

> *@Mukund : Yeah I had Jupiter installed in my system and now I had removed it and my system works perfectly. No more freezing, So thanks a lot.*

*Please vote for it..*

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug, and should be reported as one. If you find (or someone else reports) an effective workaround, that can be included in the bug report. As per [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions), [bugs are off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site) on Ask Ubuntu, so the *only* part of this question that should really be addressed here is the issue of *how* to report this bug. Detailed work and troubleshooting on bugs in Ubuntu *needs* to happen on Launchpad; otherwise, valuable work tends to be ignored and fragmented.

Power management functionality is part of [the kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), so the correct way to report this bug is to run `ubuntu-bug linux`. Detailed technical information will be sent to [Launchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchpad_%28website%29), but you will still have to describe the problem, including anything you've tried and what happened, in as much detail as possible.

One common mistake is to report power management bugs against the `acpi`  package. That's not the right way, since the `acpi` package doesn't actually perform any power management; it's just [an interface](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/acpi) for getting information about the power management that is happening in the kernel (Linux).

I recommend that you:

- Trigger the problem.
- Record the time that you triggered it.
- (Re)boot your Ubuntu system.
- Once booted back up, immediately report the bug.
- Indicate that you have done all this in your bug report, and specify the time (or approximate time) you triggered the freeze.

That may make it easier for triagers, developers, and other interested persons to identify entries in automatically attached log files that pertain to the problem.

It's a very good idea to [read this thoroughly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) before reporting this or any other bug in Ubuntu. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) is also often quite helpful.

Finally, please note that if you are reporting this bug against the downstream kernel (linux in Ubuntu, reporting on Launchpad, as described here), *you must be running (and you should have last produced the bug using) this version of the kernel, and **not** a custom-built or upstream kernel.org version*.

<sup>If you report this bug or find it already reported, feel free to subscribe [me](https://launchpad.net/~degeneracypressure) to the bug if you wish.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply, That's very kind of you. However I removed Jupiter from my system(as suggested by @Mukund), and then the system works fine. Do you think still I have to report this as a bug, because of course people will need to use Jupiter with Ubuntu without any problem. So what do you think..? thanks.

Comment: @Sudheera I don't think you are *obligated* to report this as a bug. But if you choose to do so, I think it would be helpful. (Search first--which is explained in the bug reporting resources linked to in my answer--to see if it's already been reported. If it has then you can subscribe and indicate you're affected, and, if you have any valuable information not present in the existing bug, comment with it.) I still recommend reporting the bug. BTW hopefully Mukund will post the solution as an answer soon so it can receive the bounty (as that appears to have solved the problem for you).

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` via a terminal.
2. In the grub file,  change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
    to be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
   acpi_backlight=vendor"` Save the file.
3. Then do `sudo update-grub`
4. Close terminal
5. Then go to Ubuntu Software Center
6. search for 'pm-utils'
7. click on 'more info'
8. on the add-ons: uncheck 'Utility to control ATI Radeon backlight
   functions on laptops'
9. click on 'apply changes'
10. Close and RESTART!

Now it does not freeze when I plug/un-plug the AC power and it fixed the brightness buttons on my keyboard too. :)

- Running Ubuntu 12.04 x86
- GNOME
- Acer Aspire Laptop
- Pentium B940 2.0GHz DC
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- Intel HD Graphics (shows as Intel Sandybridge Mobile x86/mmx/SSE2

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you explain how editing GRUB is related with the power problem? however I removed "Jupiter" and now my system works fine. thanks for replying...

Comment: Had the same problem again. Empirically, I noticed that I had inserted an SD card and had a GNOME extension to show and unmount removable media on the top panel. I turned off the extension, the problem went away. Seems to me that it is a problem with GNOME 3 and extensions/indicators on the top panel, since your problem was with jupiter (which is an extension or indicator program) and mine with this "Removable drive menu" extension. It has something to do with the battery indicator when you plug/unplug, as if it doesn't get along with other indicators/menus. Have to say I'm new to linux.

Comment: I think your theory explains the situation. thanks.

Comment: I kept experiencing the problem until I did a kernel upgrade to 3.5.0-21. That fixed it for me and I have no AC adapter, battery or dim screen problems.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem on my laptop (Asus A53S; Ubuntu 12.10; Kernel 3.7.0).

I did two things:

1. As [Alvar](https://askubuntu.com/users/10698/alvar) indicated, I unchecked the  'Utility to control ATI Radeon backlight functions on laptops' functionality in pm-utils
2. I updated my kernel to kernel 3.7.3, as this should fix the bug according to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51661. See [Upgrade to Linux Kernel 3.7.3](http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/01/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-373-in.html) for a manual on how to upgrade your kernel

Unfortunately I'm not sure which of the two methods did fix the issue, since I changed them both before going into reboot. However, unchecking a unnecessary feature in pm-utils is always a good idea, and updating to a new (stable) kernel too.

Answer (score 0):

its not a problem wit ubuntu 
some laptops tend to freeze when connected by power when charge is more than 75%
restarting consumes power and it works fine agai
to solve te problem just connect before starting
there mightbe a bugfix from your BIOS